# How do I disable the_content support for a certain page template?

Tags: wordpress

I have a very simple page template, simple-template.php for which I don't use the_content(). How to I remove that textarea in the backend?

Comment: So you dont want to add/edit the content in the backend? Can I ask why?

Comment: I have added some custom fields to help the user add the data and I place those exactly where he needs them. Nothing will be typed in the textarea.I just want to make that template more clean looking. Since I can have a template without featured image why can't I have without the content?

Comment: Like [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/50092/12615) or like [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/88886/12615).

Comment: I think @brasofilo has better options for you

Comment: yes, thank you brasofilo, it worked like a charm. I'm sure this will help somebody else even if it's -2 now.

Comment: It's not a good question for [so]... Belongs on [wordpress.se], albeit it would be marked as duplicate over there. Search before asking normally pays off ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so let's do this:

1. Add a theme option css file for the admin area. Add this to your functions.php file or in a sub functions file:

   ```
   add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_scripts');

   function my_admin_scripts() {
       wp_enqueue_style( 'theme-options', get_template_directory_uri() . '/your-theme-css-folder/theme-options.css' );
   }
   ```
2. Then create your theme-options.css file and place it in your theme css folder and add this:

   ```
   .edit-form-section{
       display:none;
   }
   ```

This will hide textarea in the backend.